# Show and Hide Tablix and shrink the space

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am new to Reporting Services. I am using Report Builder 3.0. I have created 6 Tablix on my report and would like to show and hide depending on the field value. Each table has 20 lines of text with header. So I need to shrink the space also. Is this right way of doing it? Please let me know. I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an expression in the Hidden property of the Tablix. For example in the hidden property if you wanted to hide a Tablix when the Sales value is zero, you could use the following expression in the Hidden property:

```
=IIF(Fields!Sales.Value=0, True, False)
```

More information is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx#Visibility).

Answer (score 0):

how to go about this expression if the Field.value is in another Dataset assigned to the Tablix.

=IIF(Fields!Sales.Value=0, True, False)